# JSON.parse(object) when getting from asyncStorage throws error: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I need to retrieve an object from local storage using React Native Android using `asyncStorage`. I am setting the object using this method:

```js
export const writeParsedContactsToStorage = async (parsedContacts) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@parsed_contacts', JSON.stringyfy(parsedContacts))
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

And then trying to get it back using this:

```js
export const getParsedContactsFromStorage = async () => {
  try {
    const parsedContacts = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@parsed_contacts');
    console.log(JSON.parse(parsedContacts));
    return parsedContacts;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

However, when I just the `JSON.parse()` method, I get the error:

`Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Without `JSON.parse()` the object returned looks like this:

```js
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]...........
```

How can I get the object out of storage in the original format?

Comment: `JSON.stringyfy`, is that a typo or do you have it like this in your code?

Comment: In addition to the question asked by @Clarity, can you show what the value of `parsedContacts` is?

Comment: Appears to already be parsed for you by that `AsyncStorage` API

Comment: @Clarity thanks - that is a typo - not in the code.